# 90's kids TV-show about teens on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, tv

This might be a tricky one but I'll do my best.
It's an American or British produced mid-90's TV show about teens aboard a spaceship facing different challenges every episode. I remember one particular episode that had a cute alien grow into a hungry and evil monster as an adult. The adult monster was a man in a suit similar to Chewbacca but with a huge wide mouth, shark like teeth and two hairy cones atop of its head sort of like horns. One of the teens threw an apple or a ball into its mouth and it just ate it.

One of the features of the spaceship interior was that it had tunnel slides that the teens would use to quickly reach lower levels.

I also remember the main/credits soundtrack which is impossible to write down but it has that creepy "haunted house" synth music effect similar to the classic old Dr Who episode credis in the 60s or 70s.
Any ideas?
It's not hypernauts, Deep water, AJs time travelers or space cases.

**UPDATE**: So thanks to the research by FuzzyBoots it turned out to be Space Cases despite my initial thought that it wasn't.

Comment: Was it animation or live action?

Comment: Live action TV-series  (alien in one episode was a man in a fur suit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you said it's not the same, but 90s TV show about kids on a spacecraft really sounds like *[Space Cases](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/SpaceCases)*

[image: Title image for Space Cases]

> Once upon a time in a school in outer space,
> There was a class of misfit kids from all around the place.
> They snuck aboard a mystery ship,
> Which soon slipped through a spacial rip,
> And now they're stuck on a long strange trip.

One of the actresses was a young Jewel Staite, of *Firefly* fame and indeed:

> The cast uses a network of unbelievably cool slide-like tubes to travel between areas of the ship. Thanks to TECHNOLOGY they can slide up just as easily as down. One episode even had the ship malfunctioning so two of them got stuck in the tubes all day

I don't know if I'd call it a minor key but the opening:

They have an episode with an extremely hungry alien that keeps growing, called "[All You Can Eaty](http://www.spacecasestv.com/details/scsea2_7/)"

> Eaty continues to eat everything in site, including the soap that Suzee uses to bathe him. By morning, Eaty has grown from a small ball of fluff into a 4 foot tall creature, and he's still eating everything in sight.

The thrown apple happens a little before 15 minutes into the episode.

Comment: It is endeed Space cases, see that video, at 7:08: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1gnq5. Creature is called [Eaty](https://spacecases.fandom.com/wiki/Eaty)

Comment: OMG THAT'S IT!!! So it was Space Cases I just remembered the soundtrack very differently and I personally didn't manage to find this info. Thanks a million @FuzzyBoots and Yaroslavl!!!